# Adding a Custom Order in Excel Sort

Tags: java, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am trying to Custom sort a Columns with order like for eg: `"A,2015,B,2015"`.

Here A,2015 is One Term. But Since each Term here is Separated by Comma, The order will have a issue, How will I be able to add the Comma in the Custom Order List

When I add A,2015 in Custom Order, It takes as
A
2015
B
2015

But I want it as
A,2015
B,2015
as the Sorting Order

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem?  In Excel, there is no issue in handling a custom list with entries that contain commas.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: OK, you may not be able to do it using a Custom List.  However, you could split the column and do it that way.  Sort by the numbers, then by the letters (or use a particular custom sort on each of the columns).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you can do this with commas in custom list items **used for sorting**, even though you can certainly add items containing a comma to a custom list.

Several work-arounds:

- Replace the commas in both the custom list and your data with some other character that does not occur in the data; sort it, then return to the original (or sort on a helper column where you have replaced the comma; then delete the helper column).
- If there will just be a single comma, as you show in your example:

  - Split the data on the comma
  - Sort on the two columns (using custom sort if needed)
  - Delete (or recombine, depending on how you did the split) the two columns
- Write a custom sort VBA routine
- The first two methods can also be automated using VBA, if necessary.